# Loops incorrectly then crashes

Tags: python, function, loops

I've got a piece of code I'm working on for a school project and the basic idea is that there's a battle between two characters where the user can input 2 attributes to each character: Strength and Skill. Now there are also modifiers for skill and strength which is the difference of the player's skill and strength attributes, divided by 5 and then rounded down respectively. Then each player has a dice roll, depending on who got the higher roll, that player gets the skill and strength modifiers added to their given attributes whilst the one that lost gets the modifiers deducted from their score. This then repeats until the strength attribute of one of them reaches 0 where that player then dies and the game ends.

In my code, the dice rolling function runs twice, and then crashes for an unknown reason I cannot identify.

```
import random
import time
import math
import sys

strength_mod = 0
skill_mod = 0

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

def str_mod(charone_str,chartwo_str):
    if charone_str > chartwo_str:
        top = charone_str
        bottom = chartwo_str
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc
    elif chartwo_str > charone_str:
        top = chartwo_str
        bottom = charone_str
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc
    elif charone_str == chartwo_str:
        top = charone_str
        bottom = chartwo_str
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc

def skl_mod(charone_skl, chartwo_skl):
    if charone_skl > chartwo_skl:
        top = charone_skl
        bottom = chartwo_skl;
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc
    elif chartwo_skl > charone_skl:
        top = chartwo_skl
        bottom = charone_skl
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc
    elif charone_skl == chartwo_skl:
        top = charone_skl
        bottom = chartwo_skl
        calc = top - bottom
        calc = calc / 5
        calc = math.floor(calc)
        return calc

def mods():
    global strength_mod
    global skill_mod
    strength_mod = str_mod(charone_strength, chartwo_strength)
    skill_mod = skl_mod(charone_skill, chartwo_skill)
    print "\nFor this battle, the strength modifier is:",strength_mod
    time.sleep(0.20)
    print "For this battle, the skill modifier is: ",skill_mod
    time.sleep(0.20)
    diceroll(charone, chartwo)
    print "\n"+str(charone)+"'s","dice roll is:",player1
    time.sleep(1)
    print "\n"+str(chartwo)+"'s","dice roll is:",player2

def diceroll(charone, chartwo):
    print "\n"+str(charone)+" will roll the 6 sided dice first!"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    global player1
    player1 = random.randint(1,6)
    delay_print("\nRolling dice!")
    global player2
    player2 = random.randint(1,6)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "\nNow",chartwo,"will roll the 6 sided dice!"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    delay_print("\nRolling dice!")

def battle(charone_str, chartwo_str, charone_skl, chartwo_skl, str_mod, skl_mod):
    global charone_strength
    global charone_skill
    global chartwo_strength
    global chartwo_skill
    if player1 == player2:
        print "\nThis round is a draw! No damage done"
    elif player1 > player2:
        charone_strength = charone_str + str_mod
        charone_skill = charone_skl + skl_mod
        chartwo_strength = charwo_skl - str_mod
        chartwo_skill = chartwo_skl - skl_mod
        print "\n"+charone+" won this round"
        print "\n"+"Character 1:",charone
        print "Strength:",charone_strength
        print "Skill:",charone_skill
        time.sleep(1)
        print "\nCharacter 2:",chartwo
        print "Strength:",chartwo_strength
        print "Skill:",chartwo_skill
    elif player2 > player1:
        chartwo_strength = chartwo_str + str_mod
        chartwo_skill = chartwo_skl + skl_mod
        charone_strength = charone_str - str_mod
        charone_skill = charone_skl - skl_mod
        print "\n"+chartwo+" won this round"
        print "\nCharacter 2:",chartwo
        print "Strength:",chartwo_strength
        print "Skill:",chartwo_skilll
        time.sleep(1)
        print "\n"+"Character 1:",charone
        print "Strength:",charone_strength
        print "Skill:",charone_skill

    if charone_skill >= 0:
        charone_skill = 0
    elif chartwo_skill >= 0:
        chartwo_skill = 0

    if charone_strength <= 0:
        print charone,"has died!",chartwo,"wins!"
    elif chartwo_strength <= 0:
        print chartwo,"has died!",charone,"wins!"

charone = raw_input("Enter the name of character one: ")
chartwo = raw_input("Enter the name of character two: ")
time.sleep(1.5)
print "\n",charone,"encounters",chartwo
delay_print("\nBattle Initiated!")

charone_strength = int(raw_input("\nEnter the strength score for "+str(charone)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
while charone_strength > 100 or charone_strength < 50:
    print "That number is not between 50-100"
    charone_strength = int(raw_input("\nEnter the strength score for "+str(charone)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
else:
    pass

charone_skill = int(raw_input("Enter the skill score for "+str(charone)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
while charone_skill > 100 or charone_skill < 50:
    print "That number is not between 50-100"
    charone_skill = int(raw_input("Enter the skill score for "+str(charone)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
else:
    pass
time.sleep(1.0)

chartwo_strength = int(raw_input("\nEnter the strength score for "+str(chartwo)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
while chartwo_strength > 100 or chartwo_strength < 50:
    print "That number is not between 50-100"
    chartwo_strength = int(raw_input("\n Enter the strength score for "+str(chartwo)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
else:
    pass

chartwo_skill = int(raw_input("Enter the skill score for "+str(chartwo)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
while chartwo_skill > 100 or chartwo_skill < 50:
    print "That number is not between 50-100"
    chartwo_skill = int(raw_input("Enter the skill score for "+str(chartwo)+" (between 50 and 100): "))
else:
    pass

time.sleep(2)
print "\nCharacter 1:",charone
print "Strength:",charone_strength
print "Skill:",charone_skill
time.sleep(1)
print "\nCharacter 2:",chartwo
print "Strength:",chartwo_strength
print "Skill:",chartwo_skill
time.sleep(1)

while charone_strength != 0 or chartwo_strength != 0:
    ent = raw_input("Press Enter to roll! ")
    mods()
    diceroll(charone,chartwo)
    battle(charone_strength, chartwo_strength, charone_skill, chartwo_skill, str_mod, skl_mod)
else:
    play = raw_input("\nWould you like to play again?")
    if play in ["yes","y","Yes","Y"]:
        execfile("gcse.py")
    else:
        print "Goodbye"
```

Comment: There's a **lot** of code here.  Pare it down to the specific method that's crashing, and allow us a snippet to reproduce just the behavior you're observing.  It'd be even better if you were to point out which part of your program was crashing.

Answer (score 2):

This code is an excellent example of how *not* to program:

- heavy use of global variables
- multiple variables with very similar names (ie `charone_strength`, `charone_str`)
- reuse of names in different contexts (in global scope, `str_mod` is a function, but in function `battle` it is *supposed* to be an integer

Your immediate problem: in line 182, you call

```
battle(charone_strength, chartwo_strength, charone_skill, chartwo_skill, str_mod, skl_mod)
```

which should be

```
battle(charone_strength, chartwo_strength, charone_skill, chartwo_skill, strength_mod, skill_mod)
```

but is confused because in the function `strength_mod` is referred to as `str_mod`.

---

Here is a greatly cleaned-up version. (Further suggestions for improvement are welcome).

```
from   __future__ import division, print_function
from   random import randint
import sys
from   time import sleep

# Python 2/3 compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    rng = range

PRINT_DELAY = 0.02
PAUSE_DELAY = 0.2
TF_VALUES   = {
    'y': True,  'yes': True,  't': True, '': True,
    'n': False, 'no':  False, 'f': False
}

def get_int(prompt="Enter an integer: ", lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(inp(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= i) and (hi is None or i <= hi):
                return i
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_tf(prompt="Yes or no? ", tf_values=TF_VALUES):
    while True:
        s = inp(prompt).strip().lower()
        tf = tf_values.get(s, None)
        if tf is not None:
            return tf

def pause(delay=PAUSE_DELAY):
    sleep(delay)

def roll(die_sides=6):
    return randint(1, die_sides)

def slow_print(s, delay=PRINT_DELAY):
    for ch in s:
        print(ch, end='', flush=True)
        sleep(delay)
    print('')   # end of line

def wait_for_enter(prompt):
    inp(prompt)


class Fighter:
    @classmethod
    def get_fighter(cls, prompt):
        print(prompt)
        name   = inp    ("Name: ")
        health = get_int("Health: (50-100) ", 50, 100)
        skill  = get_int("Skill:  (50-100) ", 50, 100)
        return cls(name, health, skill)

    def __init__(self, name, health, skill):
        self.name   = name
        self.health = health
        self.skill  = skill

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.health > 0

    def health_mod(self, other_fighter):
        delta = abs(self.health - other_fighter.health)
        return int(delta / 5)

    def skill_mod(self, other_fighter):
        delta = abs(self.skill - other_fighter.skill)
        return int(delta / 5)

    def attack(self, other_fighter):
        wait_for_enter("Hit Enter to fight!")
        # figure out mod values
        health_mod = self.health_mod(other_fighter)
        skill_mod  = self.skill_mod (other_fighter)
        self_roll  = roll()
        other_roll = roll()
        slow_print(
            "Health mod: {}   Skill mod: {}   {} rolls {}   {} rolls {}"
            .format(
                health_mod, skill_mod,
                self.name,  self_roll,
                other_fighter.name, other_roll
            )
        )
        # figure out who won this round
        if self_roll == other_roll:
            print("Draw! No damage done.")
        else:
            winner, loser = (self, other_fighter) if self_roll > other_roll else (other_fighter, self)
            print("{} hits {}!".format(winner.name, loser.name))
            winner.health += health_mod
            winner.skill  += skill_mod
            loser.health  -= health_mod
            loser.skill   -= skill_mod
        # show results
        print('')
        print(self)
        print(other_fighter)
        print('')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: health {}, skill {}".format(self.name, max(self.health, 0), max(self.skill, 0))


def fight():
    f1 = Fighter.get_fighter("\nFirst fighter:")
    pause()
    f2 = Fighter.get_fighter("\nSecond fighter:")
    pause()

    slow_print("\n{} encounters {}\nBattle Initiated!".format(f1.name, f2.name))
    while f1.is_alive() and f2.is_alive():
        f1.attack(f2)

    winner, loser = (f1, f2) if f1.is_alive() else (f2, f1)
    print("{} has died; {} wins!".format(loser.name, winner.name))

def main():
    while True:
        fight()
        if not get_tf("Would you like to play again? (Y/n)"):
            print("Goodbye!")
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```